# HTTP referrer when using with an iframe & Flash

Tags: flash, iframe, http-referer

I completed one widget with Flash, I put the `swf` file in one page that page that is attached to `iframe`.

The problem starts from here when I put this `swf` file inside of `iframe` the HTTP Referrer is not working.

If I click on the `swf` file the HTTP referrer URL showing as `iframe` url.

Is it possible to hide the `iframe` referrer?